# Parser Error "There is an error in XML document (0,0)" Salesforce Wsdl

Tags: .net, wsdl, salesforce, aspdotnetstorefront, parsing-error

I ran into this problem a long time ago, but failed to document it for me and posterity.

I have 3 machines that are running the same code.  I am running IIS on Windows XP Pro, Windows 2003 and Windows 2008.  The code comes from our original site (all the code is exactly the same) and was placed on the other environments to see if we could start development and make further changes.

Win 2003 is the current function internal server.  It runs the code without any problems.  The other 2 do not, with the same error message:

> **Parser Error**
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: There is an error in XML document (0, 0).
>
> Source Error:
>
> > [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: /site1/App_WebReferences/salesforce/    Line: 1
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3615; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

I don't think it is a problem with the Salesforce Wsdl file because it is saying the problem is with the very first line.  The declaration of the xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <!--
    Salesforce.com Enterprise Web Services API Version 21.0
    Generated on 2011-02-24 15:38:46 +0000.

    Package Versions:
    Informatica Data Loader (Version: 1.11, Namespace: infa)
    Salesforce for Google AdWords (Version: 1.2, Namespace: sfga)
    VerticalResponse for AppExchange (Version: 1.1, Namespace: vr)

    Copyright 1999-2011 salesforce.com, inc.
    All Rights Reserved
    -->

    <definitions targetNamespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" ...
```

I believe that it may have something to do with the bin files or the code that would launch the site.  Global or Application that is not functioning correctly.

I am running AspDotNetStorefront.  The newer version 9.x is running concurrently on the same Windows 2008 server.  It is running just fine.

Further, I was thinking that IIS may have locked up some files that keeps it from properly being able to compile the files that work on another server.  This is just a theory that I don't know how to test, or even find the offending file(s).  I tried deleting out all of the .NET temporary files from the windows folder after shutting down the site in IIS.  But I don't know if that is the only place for the files.  It didn't fix the problem anyways.

Comment: This is on an initial setup of IIS to run the site while IIS is running another version of ASPDotNetStorefront.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have noticed quite a few visits to this question and decided to post some of the things that I have done to fix the problem.  We just recently came across a similar issue on our site and I hope these may be useful.

First off, is to cause your entire site to recompile by touching the web.config (adding a space and then removing it and saving the web.config).  This recompile may not affect the entire site and some of the cached files may not correctly get recompiled.

So step two is to find your temporary .Net folder in the Windows directory.  Find the specific folder that contains your cached build for the site that is having problems.  As I have several sites running simultaneously I have to search on a specific filename like johnjohn.aspx.  The folders have temporary names that I wish I understood where they came from but once you have found the folder, you can back it up and delete it or rename it.  In order to do this you will probably need to stop the site. After you have deleted/renamed the folder, restart the site in IIS.

This is what I have right now.  I will check back to see if anyone else has posted solutions.